# Find and mark the intersection between two lines

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I have two CPTScatterPlots and I would like to find their intersection and draw a custom circle with fill there. Of course I could calculate it manually, but maybe core plot has this already.
see attached.
Is this possible with Core Plot?[image: CorePlot]

UPDATE based on Eric's sugestion:

```
/* Add the plot symbol for the intersection */

CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];  
symbolLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.;  
symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:91./255. green:173./255. blue:221./255. alpha:1.] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];  
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];  
plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:241./255. green:241./255. blue:241. /255. alpha:1.] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.]];  
plotSymbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;  
plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(_CIRCLE_RADIUS, _CIRCLE_RADIUS);  
dataSourceIntersectionPlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot can't find the intersection point for you, but it can mark it. If you know the lines will cross at one of the data points, just add a plot symbol to one of the plots. Implement the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method and return a symbol at the correct index.

If the lines might cross between data points, create a third plot that is used only for highlighting the crossing point. It only needs one data point with a plot symbol—the intersection point.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I can find the cross point, no problem. Let me see how it goes and will be back to mark your answer.

Comment: worked out Eric. Thanks for you help. As suggested I worked out the intersection point and then added a new CPTScatterPlot with one data point, and then added to it a CPTPlotSymbol. will update my original question to have this code section. The rest is also pretty straight forward.